# when use evalfis "Warning: Some input values are outside of the specified input range."

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

when use evalfis "Warning: Some input values are outside of the specified input range.""

```
out_fis = anfis([1,1,1;2,2,2]) 
action = evalfis([3,3] , out_fis); 
Warning: Some input values are outside of the specified input range
```

what is the specified input range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you are giving to [ANFIS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fuzzy/anfis.html) is the training data you are using to create an FIS structure `out_fis`. The first two columns of the training data contain input values, and the last column contains output values. The input values in the training data are in the range 1 to 2, but the input you are passing to [EVALFIS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fuzzy/evalfis.html) contains values outside that range.